# Trouble compiling flashbuilder project with sdk 3.*

Tags: apache-flex, flashdevelop

I have a series of projects that we have been using Flex3/Flashbuilder to work with, but I've recently been trying to move over to Flashdevelop for most of my development but I have hit a snag with a certain project structure that Flex/FB can handle but FD/mxmlc can't with sdk 3.*

What I have is something like this:

project_root/

```
 /src

 /resources
```

The resources in flex is added as a class path to the project and I am embedding images like this: [Embed(source="/wardrobe.png")]

This all works fine in Flex/FB but FD I get there errors for all my images :

Error:unable to resolve '/wardrobe.png' for transcoding
Error:unable to transcode /wardrobe.png

This problem don't occur when I'm using the Flex 4 sdk, but for these projects I require 3.2. If anyone has any idea of what these projects won't build and a way to make them work outside of Flex/FB that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

**Good news:** 
there is a reason why the Flex 3 SDK does not resolve embeds in the entire classpath but only the class' one.

**Bad news:** 
[it's a bug](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-15466) which is not going to be fixed in Flex 3 SDK (it's ok in Flex 4 SDK).
As a matter of fact, both FlashBuilder and Maven Flexmojos use a workaround (they inject a custom "resource resolver" in the compiler).

**Solution:**
The best you can do is to fix embed paths like: "/../resources/wardrobe.png" (the starting "/" makes the path relative to the class' classpath root).

Comment: Bug report was moved to Apache foundation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-14682

Answer (score -1):

try cleaning the project

i don't know where in flex builder but in eclipse it in Project>Clean

then build again the project..

Comment: Question is about working with FlashDevelop (that is without Eclipse) and has nothing to do with project cleanup.

Comment: hey, i just stated an example. i am not saying that its the answer... and its a suggestion cause sometimes i get the same error as he does..

remove the vote down.